# TypeError: something is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

First of all, let me say that I am relatively new to javascript and this code is meant to try and learn something new, so feel free to comment on anything even if it is not the concrete question I am asking.

I am currently trying to centralize my code for accessing my MySQL database in my Express js server and wanted to make use of promises. This is what I tried:

```
let mysql = require('mysql');

    var connectionPool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database',
    connectionLimit: 10
});

function getConnection() {
    return new Promise(afterConnecting => {
        connectionPool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            return afterConnecting(connection);
        });
    });
}

function queryConnection(connection, queryString) {
    return new Promise(consumeRows => {
        connection.query(queryString, function (err, rows) {
            connection.release();
            if (err) throw err;
            return consumeRows(rows);
        });
    });
}

exports.requests = {
    getAllEmployees: function () {
        const queryString = 'SELECT id, name FROM employees;
        return getConnection()
            .then(connection => {
                return queryConnection(connection, queryString);
            });
    }
};
```

I am trying to call `getAllEmployees()` like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../database');

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    db.getAllEmployees()
        .then(rows => {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.send(JSON.stringify(rows));
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My problem is that I get an TypeError stating "db.getAllEmployees is not a function". When debugging VS Code claims that `db.getAllEmployees` is indeed a function. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You export it as `exports.requests.getAllEmployees` therefore you have to use it as:

```
 db.requests.getAllEmployees()
```

Comment: My god, thank you, now I am really embarrassed. Will accept as soon as SO will let me.

Comment: @jerome glad to help :) PS: While coding I heavily rely on autocompletion to avoid such mistakes ...